# Artemis apps don't hear each other

Tags: apache, activemq-artemis

My apps have `spring-boot-starter-artemis` dependency with 1.5.8 version. External Artemis server uses 2.6.0.  One app is publishing messages to the address: *tacocloud.order.queue*:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Destination orderQueue() {
        return new ActiveMQQueue("tacocloud.order.queue");
    }

}
```

Service layer of the first app:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class JmsOrderMessagingService implements OrderMessagingService {

    private final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    private final Destination destination;

    @Override
    public void sendOrder(Order order) {
        jmsTemplate.send(destination, session -> {
            Message message = session.createObjectMessage(order);
            message.setStringProperty("X_ORDER_SOURCE", "WEB");
            return message;
        });
    }

}
```

Second app is listening on the address: tacocloud.order.queue

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class OrderReceiver {

    private final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @GetMapping("/new/message")
    public Message receiveOrder() {
        return jmsTemplate.receive("tacocloud.order.queue");
    }

}
```

Though the specified address to listen to is *tacocloud.order.queue*, in the Artemis Management console it is registered as *jms.queue.tacocloud.order.queue*.

[image]

**Question: how to make 2 apps hear each other?**

Comment: What version of Artemis are you using?

Comment: @JustinBertram 2.6.0

Comment: Can you confirm that you are indeed using Artemis 2.6.0 on both the client and the server?  The prefixes for JMS destination (i.e. "jms.queue." & "jms.topic.") were removed in Artemis 2.0.0 so I'm surprised to see a queue with that prefix in 2.6.0.

Comment: @JustinBertram my apps have spring-boot-starter-artemis dependency with 1.5.8 version. External Artemis server has 2.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either:

1. Update your client to use the latest version of `spring-boot-starter-artemis` (e.g. `2.0.3.RELEASE`).
2. Update your acceptor to use `anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.`.  This is noted in [the Artemis documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/versions.html) when upgrading from 2.4.0.

Comment: Just to clarify...Did you try option 1 and it didn't work?